# Android icon background is black in new market

Tags: android, icons

Why?

Here is one of my apps for example:

http://market.android.com/details?id=com.citc.ud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In photoshop you need to use save for web, select 24 bit png, and then check 'transparency'. This adds another 16 bit for the alpha giving you a 32bit png.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with how you designed the icon. I would suggest reading the [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) if you haven't already done that.

And if you have the PNG ready, you might also consider getting the icon generated from this link here. I use it for all my apps and it works like a charm all the time.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html